# Why is my code outputting "tryAgain cannot be resolved to a variable" in the context of a do-while loop?

Tags: java, scope

I'm new to Java and I'm trying to add a way to loop an if-else statement by asking the user if they want to try again at the end of the program, which I have attempted with a do-while loop. However, when compiling the program it outputs a java error stating that tryAgain cannot be resolved to a variable. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Simple{
        public static void main(String[] Args){
        Scanner againScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner numberScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        do{
        System.out.println("Please type an integer and I will determine whether it is odd or even.");
        int number = numberScanner.nextInt();
        if(number % 2 == 0){
            System.out.println(number + " is an even number.");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(number + " is an odd number.");
        }
        numberScanner.close();
        
        }
        while (tryAgain = true);
    System.out.println("Would you like to try again (type True or False)?");
    Boolean tryAgain = againScanner.nextBoolean();
    againScanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `tryAgain` declared?

Comment: Also, watch out: `tryAgain = true` will always be true. You probably meant `tryAgain == true`.

Comment: Also, `tryAgain = againScanner.nextBoolean();` should be read inside the loop.

Comment: You're trying to use that variable before you've declared it.  You'll need to declare it earlier.  Also think hard about which lines should be inside the loop, and which should be outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I must point out that the compilation of the java language is sequential, you must define before using any property or variable, and your tryAgain must be defined before using it.
Second, in java, any variable defined in the body of a loop is called a local variable, and it cannot be referenced by global code, so your code must be modified like this:

```
    public class Simple{
        public static void main(String[] Args){
            Scanner againScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner numberScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            Boolean tryAgain=true;
            do{
                System.out.println("Please type an integer and I will determine whether it is odd or even.");
                int number = numberScanner.nextInt();
                if(number % 2 == 0){
                    System.out.println(number + " is an even number.");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println(number + " is an odd number.");
                }
                System.out.println("Would you like to try again (type True or False)?");
                tryAgain= againScanner.nextBoolean();
            }
            while (tryAgain);
            againScanner.close();
            numberScanner.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code seems to resolve the error that tryAgain cannot be resolved to a variable, however `Boolean tryAgain=true` outputs the error "The value of the local variable tryAgain is not used". I'm unsure why this is occurring, as we have declared the variable outside of the do-while loop so it is global, and we have used the variable in the loop.

Comment: @dodecahedronpigeon Yes, there are still some problems with the previous code, I briefly scanned it, and I was negligent.Then there is no problem.